# Does a worker thread need to sleep?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep, worker-thread

A normal worker thread runs in a loop in which it checks for available tasks in a queue and consumes them. I've seem some examples where the thread waits a couple of milliseconds when there is no available task, using `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` for example. However, I want my thread to consume the tasks with minimal latency, so I don't use a sleep. Is that any bad? Should a worker thread sleep for some milliseconds when checking for tasks?

Comment: Without sleeping your thread can just waste CPU cycles with millions of checks per second, so it can use the whole one core of CPU just for checks that isn't so good

Comment: I believe the strategy is to improve your app's processing scaleability by avoiding context switches when the worker thread blocks "too soon".  With this strategy, the worker threads sleeps a little in the hopes that some work will show up, and the worker threads won't have caused a context switch.  But since your the app writer, you get to verify all of these assumptions with your expected workflows.

Comment: If the queue is any good, there should be a "blocking receive" operation which sleeps (doesn't consume cycles, doesn't busy wait) while the queue is empty and is promptly woken up via a condition variable when more work is enqueued.

Comment: If you don't sleep, not only is your buzy-wait burning cycles, it might even starve the task-producers. Anyway, it should not wait some short time, but until woken.

Comment: @delnan That sounds like the solution.

Comment: @danijar that is every frequently the simplest solution. And with the thread support library in C++11, it s quite-literally *trivial* to implement. It certainly looks like you have such features available to you. There are lots of examples even here on SO much less across the web. I would advise *not* cut/pasting one, but rather review different ones and see how they work, then craft one with the specific needs *you* have to meet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you "roll your own" queue or message system, one way to avoid consuming 100% cpu is to "sleep" for a bit when there's no work available. However, having some other mechanism that lets the OS take care of this for you (semaphore(s), OS-based queue such as pipe or mailbox system, or even using a network message passing mechanism, etc) would be much better, since it simplifies your application, and it allows the OS to take care of the sleeping/waking processing.

Of course, it all depends on what you are actually trying to achieve and what the expectation is - if your code is intended to run on, say, a mobile phone, not wasting CPU-cycles is critical, because that kills battery life as well as wasting CPU cycles that could be used on some other task. On the other hand, if your messaging system is in the ABS brakes of a car, and you require to measure the time of the pulses from the sensor with sub-microsecond accuracy, sleeping would be a bad idea, since your code will probably sleep for a lot longer than once pulse from the ABS sensor.

If it's in a desktop, nobody will care if your application doesn't sleep if it runs for a few seconds or even a minute or more. But if it keeps using 1 core at 100% for hours (and your app isn't producing something that is at least as valuable as the cycles wasted - obviously calculating the next largest prime number in the world or folding proteins is worth wasting cycles on. Saving 0.5 milliseconds on receiving a packet from the internet probably isn't).

Only you (and any other people involved in the project of course) will know what the design criteria is for your project. It is not something you can "ask the internet" about. The above should give you some guidance once you have figured out what your design criteria is, however.